# date and time in flutter

Tags: flutter, datetime, datepicker

im trying to create a do to list application for my first application. so far its going well but i want to add date and time picking in the app that where my problem began. can anyone please teach me how to create this date and time picker

how to create nice datepicker?

[image]

right now im using this

```
DatePickerDialog(
            initialDate: DateTime(2022, 5, 5),
            firstDate: DateTime(2022 - 100, 4, 4),
            lastDate: DateTime(2022 + 100, 7, 7),
          )
```

but im not satisfied with the result, i think u need to use wheel but idk how to use it

Answer (score 0):

```
DatePicker( 
   looping = (true or false) //your choice
   firstDate: DateTime(xxxx, yy, zz),
      lastDate: DateTime(xxxx, yy, zz),
      initialDate: DateTime(xxxx, yy, zz),
      dateFormat: "h:mm :a", 
      locale: DatePicker.localeFromString('en'),
      onChange: (DateTime newDate, _) => _selectedDate = newDate,
      pickerTheme: DateTimePickerTheme(
        itemTextStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.green, fontSize: 19),
        dividerColor: Colors.red,
      ),

)
```